# Integration in R giving "non-finite function value"

Tags: r

```
integral <- function(x) {2.393794315*((3320)*(x/2.24581)^5+(-1613880/11)*(x/2.24581)^4+(171163181/66)*(x/2.24581)^3+(-7563546913/330)*(x/2.24581)^2+(835541173981/8250)*(x/2.24581)+(-2953570085669/16500))*(((483793.161846485)*x^8+(-76823340.9717028)*x^7+(5337025908.822)*x^6+(-211866341077.587)*x^5+(5256530719898.47)*x^4+(-83466263852549.1)*x^3+(828318375700455)*x^2+(-4697211251008830)*x+(11653475160809900))^0.5)}

integrate(integral, lower=19.538547, upper=20.3245805)
```

This gave me

> Error in integrate(integral, lower = 19.538547, upper = 20.3245805) : 
>     non-finite function value

I am not sure what to do. It'd be great if somebody could input the integral into a software like Maple to see if it works - or, giving an answer to how to get around this error would be great, too :P

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The function that I am trying to revolve around the x-axis is:

y=2.393794315*((3320)*(x/2.24581)^5+(-1613880/11)*(x/2.24581)^4+(171163181/66)*(x/2.24581)^3+(-7563546913/330)*(x/2.24581)^2+(835541173981/8250)*(x/2.24581)+(-2953570085669/16500))

When plotted with limits {19.538547 < x < 20.3245805}:

[image]

As in the link provided by @StephenWade (in the comments), to find the surface area, I needed (f'(x))^2 + 1. Using Wolfram, Alpha, I computed this to be:

(f'(x))^2 + 1 = (483793.161846485)*x^8+(-76823340.9717028)*x^7+(5337025908.822)*x^6+(-211866341077.587)*x^5+(5256530719898.47)*x^4+(-83466263852549.1)*x^3+(828318375700455)*x^2+(-4697211251008830)*x+(11653475160809900)

Plotting this, without limits, gives:

[image]

However, computing this on R, I got an error:

[image]

My input into R was the following:

2.393794315*((3320)*(x/2.24581)^5+(-1613880/11)*(x/2.24581)^4+(171163181/66)*(x/2.24581)^3+(-7563546913/330)*(x/2.24581)^2+(835541173981/8250)*(x/2.24581)+(-2953570085669/16500))*(((483793.161846485)*x^8+(-76823340.9717028)*x^7+(5337025908.822)*x^6+(-211866341077.587)*x^5+(5256530719898.47)*x^4+(-83466263852549.1)*x^3+(828318375700455)*x^2+(-4697211251008830)*x+(11653475160809900))^0.5)

I just need a reasonable estimate of the surface area...Any ideas?

Comment: `integral(20)` gives ǸaN.

Comment: Maple has trouble integrating it. I tried Derive and got tired of waiting for it to terminate, although when I requested an approximation of the integral it gave the warning that the result would have "dubious accuracy". You need to rescale somehow. Perhaps do a change of variables so e.g. it is an integral of a function with smaller coefficients over a bigger range. You might need to consult with an expert on numerical analysis since naïve solutions (even if they return a value) might run into the dubious accuracy that Derive warned against.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for your attempt on Maple. I am a high school student, and am not sure how I can proceed. I was trying to revolve a fifth order polynomial around the x-axis to find the surface area...any reasonable estimate of the integral would work; could you help me out?

Comment: Can you check your work against the formula in  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html ? I would guess the square root is a problem. If R tries to take the square root of a negative number, it returns NaN

Comment: What is the 5th degree polynomial that you are trying to integrate? What I would do is write an R function which takes a vector of coefficients corresponding to a polynomial and returns the integrand. Test it with polynomials of small degree. Apply it to yours.

Comment: Plot the function between your lower and upper bound.  Does it look nice?  Change the scale if you run into numerical problems.  BTW, using name ```integral``` for integrand is a bit confusing.

Comment: @StephenWade Yes, my integrand matches the formula in mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html...Please refer to my edit.

Comment: @JohnColeman Please refer to my edit for more information regarding the polynomial and integration. I did not understand what you meant by "write an R function which takes a vector of coefficients corresponding to a polynomial and returns the integrand..." - Could you please explain it to me in simpler terms?

Comment: @OttToomet Please refer to my edit. What do you mean by "change the scale if you run into  numerical problems"? How should I proceed from this point?

Comment: The graph is of f(x), and not (f'(x))^2 + 1

Comment: Oops I just realised that - can you please plot 1+(f'(x))^2 or the integrand - not the function y?

Comment: There is no reason for you to expand out the square before plugging it into `integrate`.

Comment: @StephenWade I have edited my question to show 1+(f'(x))^2, which, for some reason, does go negative. I used Wolfram Alpha to find the derivative as well as 1+(f'(x))^2, which is strange. Plotting the integrand gave me an error....I am not sure how to proceed (I have double checked that the function is correct, and 1+(f'(x))^2 is correct by Wolfram Alpha)...

Comment: The tangent lines are almost vertical at places. Thus, you are straining floating point math. You need to rescale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it using the `polynom` package, which can calculate the derivative for us, and then apply the formula from Wolfram.

```
revol_coef <- 2.393794315 * c(-2953570085669 / 16500,
                              835541173981 / (8250 * 2.24581),
                              -7563546913/ (330 * 2.24581^2),
                              171163181 / (66 * 2.24581^3),
                              -1613880 / (11 * 2.24581^4),
                              3320 / 2.24581^5)
y <- polynomial(revol_coef)
y_d <- deriv(y)

f <- function(x) {
    2 * pi * predict(y, x) * sqrt(1 + predict(y_d, x)^2)
}


integrate(f, lower = 19.538547, upper = 20.3245805)
```

The output I get is

```
-45.71118 with absolute error < 0.0017
```

The answer is negative, due to the surface being specified in the lower-right quadrant of the x-y plane (as per your plot). To fix this, take the negative of the number supplied to get a surface area.

Translating formulas from Wolfram Alpha, manipulating them, and then putting them into R can easily involve making a mistake.

In this case, I would recommend doing as much of the work within R, as the tools/functions to do the necessary calculations and simplifications are readily available.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this! Have a great day! :)

Comment: Make sure you understand each step as everyone (including myself) can make mistakes. I have made no attempt to verify my answer.